# How macOs counts disk usage

Tags: osx, disk-usage

I recently started using macOS moving over from Linux for work. I found that macOs reports of it's own free space is inconsistent. Right now:

- About Mac > Storage reports 68.16GB free
- Disk Utility reports "Available" 84.73GB
- `df -h` utility reports 63Gib free, which I think is ~68GB, so that matches "About Mac".

Does anyone know why is there this discrepancy? On Linux or FreeBSD I can trust command line tools to report the right system information. Can I trust them on Mac as well or are they limited in some way (as odd as it sounds, yes)? I would expect a tool like Disk Utility to match `df`. Thank you.